# How to arrange the_content() in Wordpress post page?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to format my single post page template that has custom types. I'm using the_content() which displays the post contents altogether, but how can I call individual content fields so that I can arrange them in the template?

**functions.php**

```
function stories_init() {
$args = array(
  'label' => 'Stories',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'stories'),
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-video-alt',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'custom-fields',

        'thumbnail',)



    );
register_post_type( 'stories', $args );
}
```

**single-post.html**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Comment: What do you want to communicate with *how can I call individual content fields so that I can arrange them in the template?* And by the way; you can create a file called:. "**single-stories.php**" and do all your customisation in that File...

Comment: I want to access the content in different divs. For instance I would like the title to appear in a different column than text from the editor. So I'm trying to return just the custom-fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create custom fields to be used in posts if you wanted to separate out parts of your content, like each paragraph individually or something. `the_content()` will always print out the entire content.

If you want a plugin to do it, this is the most popular
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Or, when creating a new post, you can go to the top and click `Screen Options` then check the `Custom Fields box`.

Custom fields will appear under your post content box. You can create a new one and give it a value (They act as key/value pairs).

to call it in your template, use `<?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>`

`$post_id` -> is the ID of the post you want the meta values for. Use `$post->ID` to get a post's ID within the `$post` variable scope. Use `get_the_ID()` to retrieve the ID of the current item in the WordPress Loop.

`$key` -> is a string containing the name of the meta value you want.

`$single` can either be `true` or `false`. If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for.  Is there a way to delete custom fields?

Comment: If you just wanted to delete on a specific post, you could do it on the screen where you create the post in the wordpress admin. If you wanted to delete a custom field across all posts, you would be best to go into phpmyadmin and do a SQL query to delete it from everything in one shot. Maybe there is a simpler way to do it, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since the name of your Custom-Post is `stories`, you are better-off creating a specialized File with the name: `single-stories.php` inside your theme's directory. Inside that file you could do something like this:

```
<?php 
    // FILE-NAME: single-stories.php

    if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $id= get_the_ID(); // IN CASE YOU NEED IT ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
            <span class="entry-author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span>
            <span class="entry-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <!-- YOU CAN DO AS YOU WISH IN THIS FILE -->
            <!-- AND THE RENDERING HERE WILL BE UNIQUE TO THE CUSTOM STORIES POSTS -->
            <!-- HOWEVER, BE INFORMED THAT THIS IS FOR DETAILED (SINGLE-POST) VIEW ONLY -->
        <?php endwhile;  ?>
    <?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I guess I worded my question poorly, but Nate was able to decipher me.